# git error: object file

Tags: git, github, error-handling

I'm new to Git and I'm receiving these errors. If I run git status, it returns "bad object HEAD" and when I run git gc it returns the error messages. My computer shutdown while I was working in Git but would anyone how to resolve this?

```
 error: object file .git/objects/88/c64ab417c485b017e14cd7ca23f0cde3c7eb23 is empty
 error: object file .git/objects/88/c64ab417c485b017e14cd7ca23f0cde3c7eb23 is empty
 fatal: loose object 88c64ab417c485b017e14cd7ca23f0cde3c7eb23 (stored in .git.objects/88/c64ab417c485b017e14cd7ca23f0cde3c7eb23) is corrupt
```

Comment: Like you were in the middle of committing the first revision? If that's the case, then there's nothing to lose so I'd just "start over" (remove .git directory, ```git init ./```).

Comment: If you already had some revisions you don't want to lose, then you might want to consider actually "recovering" your stuff. Is there any output from ```git reflog```? Also, look in here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Maintenance-and-Data-Recovery

Comment: If I run git reflog I get bad object HEAD

Comment: Well... coming back to the question: is there anything on that repo that you want to recover? Cause if you were trying to create your **very first** commit on it, then there's nothing to _recover_ and you could just start over as I said on the first comment. If the answer is **yes** then you might want to hunt down the revisions that you had created on the repo and so you could start with a ```git fsck --full```

Comment: Thanks for your help! The answer is yes and when I run git fsck --full it gives me the two error messages and fatal loose object message like I posted. How would I go about that fixing those revisions?

Comment: Well.... if objects are damaged, I don't think there's the possibility of recovery for them. What I think you should do is find is the latest revision object that you can and make master point to it (```git branch master the-rev-id```) and then continue from there.